# Annotate by extra field

Tags: django, django-models, group-by

I have this models:

```
class Place(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()
  price= models.IntegerField()
```

I want to get a list of the first letters of institutions:

```
places = Place.objects.all() 
places = places.extra(select={'group_field':'LCASE(SUBSTRING(places_place.name, 1, 1))'})
places = places.values('group_field')
places = places.annotate(count=Count('group_field'))
```

Or get a list of the price:

```
places = Place.objects.all()
places = place.extra(select={'group_field':'IF(price<200, \'<200\', \'>=200\')'})
places = places.values('group_field')
places = places.annotate(count=Count('group_field'))
```

I got the error «Cannot resolve keyword 'group_field' into field. Choices are: name».

How do I group places by extra field and calculate the count by each letters?

Answer (score 2):

```
places = places.values('first_letter').annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by()
```

'order_by()' is required for your count, see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#order-by

Answer (score 0):

You should annotate with a count of different places (having the same first letter):

```
p = Place.objects.all()
p = p.extra(select={'first_letter': 'SUBSTR(name,1,1)'})
p = p.values('first_letter').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

You have to choose the field to annotate which is unique for every place. So ID is the best fit.

[Interesting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-values-clauses) the behavior of the `values` method used with annotations:

> If the `values()` clause precedes the `annotate()`, the annotation will be computed using the grouping described by the `values()` clause.

Comment: Sory. I too simplified my code. I need a grop by my froup_field